# Unicode in Delphi form TRectangle TText

Tags: delphi, unicode, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I'm new to Delphi & in DelphiXE4 editor I am trying to make chessboard gui on form, using x64 TRectangle for board (alternate colors). I want to add unicode chess pieces but in ObjectInspector properties when I add unicode it displays literally on the form. How can I add Unicode to TText (so the form displays unicode as chess pieces)?
(After I want to add dragndrop to TRectangles/unicode chess-any ideas?).

```
Rectangle63: TRectangle;
Rectangle64: TRectangle;
Text1: TText;
Text2: TText;
```

Here is screenshot showing problem:
[image: DelphiXe4 FMX TRectangle TText Unicode char not displaying]

I'm most grateful for help, thanks

EDIT:
Jeroen's answer worked to solve this for me (which I did by copy/paste the actual unicode chess piece image into TText text property). I add screenshot of exe so far. Next up I want to add DRAGNDROP to these pieces.....

[image: DelphiXe4 FMX Trectangle TText Unicode Chessboard correct]

EDIT2:
(Jeroen-font size issue fixed)
Fixed unicode black king display-see screenshot:
[image: Fixed unicode black king display]

Comment: Hi David-thx for reply-The project is as Firebird desktop ..uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Rtti, System.Classes,
  System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects;        I guess this makes it FMX?

Comment: OK-thx for link-I see it is FireMonkey (not as I called it Firebird-where did that come from!?-sorry) FMX.  My question remains though how do I do this chess gui project with unicode chess pieces in Delphi using Xe4 (either VCL or FMX)?

Comment: Thank you, that's better. I didn't make it clear that you should retain the general delphi tag. I added it back. So as a rule you tag the question delphi **and** delphi-xe4. Of course, if you ask a question that you believe does not depend on the version, you can omit the version tag.

Comment: You should phrase "(After I want to add dragndrop to TRectangles/unicode chess-any ideas?)." in a separate question.

Comment: Hi Jeroen..I still cannot get DND to work with this & so have posted a new question to ask for help on this DragNDrop-see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232577/drag-and-drop-unicode-ttext-in-delphixe4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Unicode Chess Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode) can be shown in any Delphi application provided you have a fond that contains the [Glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) for the various [CodePoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) in [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) representing the [Chess Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece).

> Actually, it does not matter what platform or development environment
>   you use, as long as they support Unicode and you have the right font.

You need:

1. a means to enter these Unicode CodePoints
2. a font representing these Unicode CodePoints as Glyphs on your target platform

To start with the last, for [Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), these fonts work fine:

- [Segoe UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe#Segoe_UI)
- [Tahoma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahoma)
- [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS)

For entering these there are two approaches on [Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows):

1. if you enable it in the registry: enter [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows) Unicode CodePoint numbers through [Alt-codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) on the keyboard
2. [copy/paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste#Copy_and_paste) them from an application (i.e. [Unicode Input: Selection from Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Selection_from_a_screen)) that provides them as text

For copy/paste, I often go to a web page with the correct characters using a [Web Browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser) that supports Unicode, or search for them using the [Character Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map) application.

To make copy/paste easier:

- These are the white pieces: ♔♕♖♗♘♙
- These are the black pieces: ♚♛♜♝♞♟

Example FireMonkey form with all the pieces in 1 [TText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Objects.TText) in one [TTRectangle](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Objects.TRectangle):

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [dkDesktop, dkiPhone, dkiPad]
  DesignerMobile = False
  DesignerWidth = 0
  DesignerHeight = 0
  DesignerDeviceName = ''
  DesignerOrientation = 0
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    Height = 50.000000000000000000
    Width = 80.000000000000000000
    object Text1: TText
      Color = claBlack
      Height = 50.000000000000000000
      Text = #9812#9813#9814#9815#9816#9817#9818#9819#9820#9821#9822#9823
      Width = 80.000000000000000000
    end
  end
end
```

*Edit*

I think you have a font size issue in your form file. Create a new question with the text of your form file. Two ways to do that:

1. open Notepad, and in notepad open the .FMX file that goes with your form; copy the text to the clipboard
2. In Delphi, right click on the form then choose "View as Text", select all the text and copy it to the clipboard, right click on your form text then select "View as Form".

Paste the code at http://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/ then post that link in a new question. After that comment here you did and I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for your helpful reply. I really do not know how to use the code you give here as I am such a beginner in DelphiXE4. However just using your suggestion to copy/paste the actual unicode image into the TText text property box gives the unicode display (see my original question where I have edited a screenshot). BTW the Black King unicode image is not the same font as the white king! Anyway I should now look into how to enable dragndrop to this Delphi code...Thanks & best wishes

Comment: See the edit I'm about to make on the answer. I've been a beginner too (:

Comment: Sample code is now here: https://bitbucket.org/jeroenp/besharp.net/commits/9df6bab9ccee17b49a304f3bb9abb94c74d91f76