# Drag and drop unicode TText in DelphiXe4

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-xe4

I am trying to make a chessboard gui in DelphiXE4 with TRectangle & TText using unicode chess pieces (see [StackOverflow Delphi chess unicode link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189143/unicode-in-delphi-form-trectangle-ttext?noredirect=1#comment24892586_17189143)and drag and drop but I cannot get DND to work properly! My test project is FireMonkey FMX.
I have tried various code additions to DragDrop/DragOver Events including using Accept & Source in code but to no result.

I set dragdrop to auto on TRectangle & TText components & can get drag function but no drop function! What code do I need to enter in Events DragDrop DragOver on target TRectangle to accept the drop event? (I am very confused with this & cannot find clear instruction on Google search anywhere!)

Here is my basic test code (on Form):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Rtti, System.Classes,
  System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    Rectangle2: TRectangle;
    Rectangle3: TRectangle;
    Rectangle4: TRectangle;
    Rectangle5: TRectangle;
    Rectangle6: TRectangle;
    Rectangle7: TRectangle;
    Rectangle8: TRectangle;
    Rectangle9: TRectangle;
    Text1: TText;
    procedure Rectangle7DragOver(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
      const Point: TPointF; var Accept: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Rectangle7DragOver(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
  const Point: TPointF; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  if Sender is TText then 
    Accept := True;
end;

end.
```

Most grateful for help & look forward to replies-thanks

EDIT/UPDATE

Here is code from bummi:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Rtti, System.Classes,
  System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Objects, FMX.Edit;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    Text1: TText;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Rectangle1DragOver(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
      const Point: TPointF; var Accept: Boolean);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation    
{$R *.fmx}    
procedure TForm3.Rectangle1DragOver(Sender: TObject;
  const Data: TDragObject; const Point: TPointF; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Caption := Data.Source.ClassName ;
  Accept := Data.Source is TText;       
end;    
end.
```

However even with this I  still cannot get my chess example to work for me! Oh dear aaargh!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to Accept if the Source of then TDragObject is TText.

```
 Accept := Data.Source is TText;
```

Sender would be your Rectangle7, or any component Rectangle7DragOver is assigned to.

Comment: Hi bummi I have just tried your code/advice but I still am not getting TText to DND! Could you post the full form with working code so I can see exactly how your code is entered and works? Thanks

Comment: There i not any more code than above shown. Did you set DragMode of your TText to dmAutomatic?

Comment: Add for debugging to your Rectangle7DragOver `Caption := Data.Source.ClassName ;` Works for me with plain form, Rectangle as Target, TText and TEdit as Sources ...

Comment: Thx bummi for your further help.. I though am missing something here as I cannot get it to work! Can you please post your full working code so I can see what to do/where I am going wrong? Most grateful thanks...

Comment: Thx for your attached files... I have to go to work right now but when back home this evening I will check them out-thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32180/discussion-between-rpd-and-bummi)